# Pass function to class when initialize (java)

Tags: java

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import button.names.constants.Constants;

public abstract class FirstSwingExample implements ActionListener {

    private static void drawFrame(JFrame frame) {
        frame.setSize(800, 400);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        drawFrame(frame);

        JButton button = new JButton(Constants.CLICK);

        frame.add(button);

        ActionListener actionListener = new CreateActionListener();

        int xButtonPosition = ((frame.getWidth() / 2) - Constants.WIDTH / 2);
        int yButtonPosition = ((frame.getHeight() / 2) - Constants.HEIGHT / 2);

        button.addActionListener(actionListener);
        button.setBounds(xButtonPosition, yButtonPosition, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);

    }
}

class CreateActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // need function here
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java. I want to make reusable listener which I will be reusing when I initialize listener. I come from `js` and there I can pass params, and get it in constructor.

How can I make the same? or what is better way to make it in my code?

Comment: What do you want to do? Execute the same action from different buttons? Also, what do you mean by the comment "need function here"? Do you already have a function available that should be called by the `ActionListener`?

Comment: What do you mean in "*I want to make reusable listener which I will be reusing when I initialize listener*"? It can be re-used, per se.. but it's not clear what do you really mean. Also, "*I can pass params, and get it in constructor*" - get what? pass params where? please be more clear in your question and specify exactly what do you want to achieve.

Comment: You can pass a parameter to a constructor. `public CreateActionListener( ActionListener e){ this.listener = e;}` then your "needed function" is just `listener.actionPerformed(e);`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use lambda expressions, which are similar to JS "arrow functions". So if you want to avoid instantiating an `ActionListener` explicitly, you could just use

```
button.addActionListener(e -> doSomethingWithE(e))
```

where `doSomethingWithE` could be any expression.

Answer (score 0):

I like using methods references, no additional class needed:

```
void someMethod() {
    // ...
    button.addActionListener(this::handleButton); // similar to (e -> handleButton(e))
    // ...
}

private void handleButton(ActionEvent ev) {
    // do something
}
```

Action listeners are just classes, they can have constructors with arguments:

```
class CreateActionListener implements ActionListener {
    CreateActionListener(/* argument list */) {
        // ...
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // need function here
    }
}
```

or even accept a *function*

```
class CreateActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private Runnable function;  // or Consumer<ActionEvent> function
    CreateActionListener(Runnable function) {
        this.function = function;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        function.run();  // function.accept(ev)
    }
}
```

and you can add a method to change the function:

```
class CreateActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private Runnable function;  // or Consumer<ActionEvent> function
    // ...
    public void setFunction(Runnable function) {
        this.function = function;
    }
}
```

<sub>it is also possible to change listeners, but not sure about that</sub>

<sup>just some ideas, I prefer first option and have logic inside the method to handle the action (for example based on some `enum` variable)</sup>